# Python load txt into array with string

Tags: python, arrays, string, load

I want to load my following from txt into an array.

From :

```
ATOM      1  N   ASP P   1     -13.459   3.135 -11.039  1.00  0.00      PROT N
ATOM      2  HT1 ASP P   1     -13.111   4.105 -11.181  1.00  0.00      PROT H
ATOM      3  HT2 ASP P   1     -14.481   3.257 -11.190  1.00  0.00      PROT H
```

To two arrays :

```
[[ 'ATOM', '1', 'N', 'ASP', 'P', '1' ], [ 'ATOM', '1', .....] ]
```

and an array of float for later numpy.dot calculation

```
array([ [-13.459, 3.135, -11.039], [-13.111, 4.105, -11.181], [....] ])
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Is tab you separator ? look at csv .

Comment: try this `inp="ATOM      1  N   ASP P   1     -13.459   3.135 -11.039  1.00  0.00      PROT N"
lst=inp.split()
lst1=[]
lst2=[]
lst1.append(lst[0:5])
lst2.append(lst[6:9])
`

Comment: I should have made it clearer. The second one I need it be an array with floats.
Thanks Vignesh, but how should I convert it into float array instead of string later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading `str.split` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator

You can do it without regex using only the `split` function.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
with open("stackoverflow.txt", "r") as f:  
    for line in f.readlines():
        l = line.split()
        list1.append(l[:6])
        list2.append(l[6:9])
print list1
print list2
```

result

```
[['ATOM', '1', 'N', 'ASP', 'P', '1'], ['ATOM', '2', 'HT1', 'ASP', 'P', '1'], ['ATOM', '3', 'HT2', 'ASP', 'P', '1']]
[['-13.459', '3.135', '-11.039'], ['-13.111', '4.105', '-11.181'], ['-14.481', '3.257', '-11.190']]
```

Thanks Vignesh Kalai for the comment.

Comment: you could just use `split() rather then converting space and then splitting`

Comment: What if I want list2 as an array of floats? I tried array('f', list2). It doesn't work with list. For astype, it only works for array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works!

```
var="ATOM 1 N ASP P 1 -13.459 3.135 -11.039 1.00 0.00 PROT N"
list=var.split() 
list1=[] list2=[] 
list1.append(list[0:5]) 
list2.append(list[6:9])
```

Comment: @Chaker that is no reason to downvote just comment about it say it effect